# How to use hibernate stored procedure query with result set transformer

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, stored-procedures

This is how i am calling a sql server stored procedure

```
public Response<List<CollectionItem>> getCollectionList(int customerId) {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("Sp_Tab_GetCollectionInvoice");
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("CustomeriD", int.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Ccode", int.class, ParameterMode.IN);


        query.setParameter("CustomeriD", customerId);
        query.setParameter("Ccode", 1);

        List<CollectionItem> resultList = query.unwrap(Query.class)
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CollectionItem.class)).getResultList();

        return new ResponseUtil().createResponse(resultList);

    }
```

This is the pojo class

```
public class CollectionItem {

    public long ID;
    public String TransType;
    public long Invno;
    public String TDate;
    public double Amount;


    public CollectionItem(long ID, String TransType, long Invno, String TDate, double Amount) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.TransType = TransType;
        this.Invno = Invno;
        this.TDate = TDate;
        this.Amount = Amount;
    }
}
```

But it is not transforming the result and it is giving a list of object array

How can i correctly map the object array to the pojo class?

Should I manually convert the object array to the pojo by running a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this issue but, `EntityManager.createStoredProdecureQuery` has a second argument used to specify the return type. What happens when you change the call like the following (also comment the line that you set ResultTransformer) ?:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("Sp_Tab_GetCollectionInvoice", CollectionItem.class);
```

If the above solution does not work, I suspect the columns returned from the stored procedure do not match the POJO class members as required. You can write a mapping using `<sql-result-set-mapping>` or the corresponding annotation to map your result set to your class members. Hibernate's query interface also has methods to handle this mapping programmatically as far as I remember. You might want to check `addRoot()` and `addProperty()` methods.

**Note:** I just noticed that your `CollectionItem` class is not annotated with `@Entity`. I am not sure if the above solution would work in this case. If you do not want to add `@Entity` and use result transformer, I think your `CollectionItem` class needs a constructor with no arguments. For bean transformer to work, Hibernate requires that the class either has no constructor or a public no-argument constructor.